# SignalR client Side Json serializer

Tags: c#, json, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following

```
class A : ISomthing{}

Class B : ISomthing{}

interface ISomthing{}

Class C { public ISomthing _member {get;set}}
```

and i try to send the following object from my .net signalR client to my hub ,I'm using signalR 2.0.2

```
C obj = new C();
obj._member  = new A();
```

I receive the following error ,Could not create an instance of type ISomthing . Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

In my client and server side I'm using JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;

Update : 
The object can be serialized by it self, using the signalR serializer :
    var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    _hubProxy.JsonSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj );

Comment: Your code is incorrect - `object` is reserved word in C#, so make it `C obj = new C();`

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Works with the serializer manually but not when calling hub.Invoke from a C# client to a C# server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not currently supported , see my question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197842/signalr-and-customtypeconverter?noredirect=1#comment33898151_22197842)

And the answer I got :
"The DependencyResolver has an IParameterResolver registered which is responsible for deserializing server-side inputs. The IParameterResolver is implemented by DefaultParameterResolver which does not use the JsonSerializer registered the DependencyResolver. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919135(v=vs.118).aspx"

Comment: Except that the IParameterResolver is EXACTLY what you want (at least in SignalR v2) - it can do this.  I just implemented the ability for my code to accept interface-type parameters of immutable in my SignalR methods.  I've also got SignalR's JSON.Net instance customised with a specific type converter, although that's not strictly required for this.